# Is it possible to filter Task list by other properties than createdBy?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to filter the task list ("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/me/tasks") by properties like dueDateTime or completedDateTime?

The request "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/me/tasks?$filter=completedDateTime ge 2016-03-03T00:00:00Z" is accepted but the filter is ignored. The Microsoft Graph Documentation says, that only createdBy is supported.

In my scenario I would like to get all tasks, that have been completed in a certain month.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to filter tasks by dueDateTime or completedDateTime right now. We have that in the backlog though and plan to add support for such filters in the future.