# How can I get My Pending Tasks from Planner using Graph

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm looking for a way to get My tasks from Planner (Office 365) and show them in a SharePoint Online site.
I tried using Microsoft Graph since it's the only way I could work with the Planner API but couldn't find how to filter pending tasks.
I'm trying with the https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/tasks?$filter=assignedTo eq 'me' endpoint and https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/tasks and trying to filter for percentComplete or even sort tasks by completedDateTime but it doesn't work.

I found this question here and it's about a yer ago but no answer so far
[Is it possible to filter Task list by other properties than createdBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35768660/is-it-possible-to-filter-task-list-by-other-properties-than-createdby)

Answer (score 0):

Currently we do not support filters in the requests. You'll need to run /me/tasks to get all tasks assigned to you, and then filter by PercentComplete on the client side. Please feel free to add a feature request for this at our Office Dev User Voice site - https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis.